# Asp.net Unable to Connect to MSSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database-connection

When I try to launch the web project in asp.net with MSSQL, it seems like I cannot connect to my database. The error message is:

```
A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server...
```

But when I try to run my previous projects, it works. However, when I select All Program -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services. Instead of listing all the services, it shows me an error which is The remote procedure call failed.

I wonder how to fix this as it only happens for one of my project. Thanks in advance.

[image: Snapshots of SQL Server Configuration Manager]

[image: Snapshots of services]

My web.config codes:

**EDIT**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="GeospatialChallenge2014.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap" />
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="GeospatialChallengeConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SAFETY_AT_SG_DATABASE.mdf;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <applicationSettings>
    <GeospatialChallenge2014.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="GeospatialChallenge2014"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost/SgDataService.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </GeospatialChallenge2014.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And my connection string:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

using System.Xml;

namespace Geospatial_Challenge_2014
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SgDataService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SgDataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public DataSet GetTrafficByDateTime(string StartDateTime, string EndDateTime)
        {
            //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            //myConn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SAFETY_AT_SG_DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GeospatialChallengeConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from dbo.Traffic where Convert(DateTime,([date]+' '+[time])) >= @StartDateTime AND Convert(DateTime,([date]+' '+[time])) <= @EndDateTime;", myConn);
            myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", StartDateTime);
            myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateTime", EndDateTime);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            myConn.Open();
            myAdapter.Fill(ds, "Traffic");
            myConn.Close();
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Down voter please specify which part that I did wrongly. I don't mind to change.

Comment: Do you using connection string in web config ?. If so, check whether your current database connection in initial catalog is correct or not ?

Comment: @gkrishy See my updated portion. Do I did anything wrong in the web config or connection string?

Comment: You should not add .mdf at connection string. Try by removing .mdf. Simply add database name alone. Are you getting something like cannot connect to database error ?

Comment: Yeah, Could not open a connection to SQL Server error message

Comment: Your connection string tries to connect to a regular SQL Server instance but you only have SQL Server Express running on your machine. Try '.\SQLEXPRESS' as the data source.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But it tells me unrecognized escape sequence after the "\"

Comment: So escape it. Or put a `@` before the first quote. Or store the configuration string in `web.config`. The settings dialog also allows you to enter a connection string and test the connection.

Comment: Could you show me some example to store the data source in web.config?

Comment: `myConn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SAFETY_AT_SG_DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: Visual Studio already has an [editor for application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ApplicationSetting);k(Designer_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsDesigner);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(SolutionItemsProject)). Add a setting of type `(Connection String)`, click the button with `...` in the `Value` column to bring up [the dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.dataconnectiondialog.connection.sqlserver)) and test the connection before saving it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Any ideas? Is it because of my connection string or the database setup on my laptop

Comment: Check with my updated answer. And before that, please let me know the details, 1. Whether you installed sql server(management studio) on local machine ?, 2. Or accessing remotely ?, 3. You are using SQL server 2008 right ?.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and helps given. I've solved it by changing some part of my web config. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude define the connection string inside your web.config itself and try.Like,

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=yourservername;Initial    
Catalog=DBname;User ID=sa;Password=yourpassword" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and inside your method call the connection string as

```
SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection();//sql connection object
objConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["DBConnection"].ConnectionString; //conn string name as in config file
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("YourStoredprocedure", objConnection);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve it. The error message is the same.

Comment: The above should work plz try it step by step carefully.

Comment: I did followed it step by step but it still tells me the same error message which is could not open a connection with SQL server. Any ideas?

Comment: ok share your entire code.config file and connection method dude.

Comment: Is there any site for me to put the codes like JsFiddle? Cause I think it might be too long to post at stackoverflow

Comment: No show post it here it self. The cobfig file and the connection method

Comment: Check my edited portion at the top. I've updated it.

Comment: Oh no dude remove that .mdf in "Catalog=SAFETY_AT_SG_DATABASE.MDF" and (local) remove those brackets and try to give server name insead of local and add username and password fiends as **User ID=sa;Password=yourpassword**

Comment: But I am using the created database in visual studio 2012. Does that have server name, user ID and password? I not sure how to find server name as well.

Comment: Where is that database its in SQLserver know?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? I am kind of lost. Would you mind to provide me some tutorial or useful links?

Comment: Login to sqlserver with username and password.In general user name will be **sa** and check your **password** and once you login richt click the folder structure and select properties as **Properites** and the first row will be **Server-Name**

Comment: Ok after login run this query to get **server name** SELECT @@SERVERNAME

Comment: I do not have SQL server management server studio installed. Is there any other ways to let me log into sqlserver? Also, with the connection string in web config, it created another database in my project

Comment: Is SQL SERVER installed in your local machine or your are trying to access remotly. If not in local machine then ask the login credentials from your TL or whoever and at any cost you need login credentials else you cant go further sorry buddy.

Comment: From your codes above, it created another empty database in my project. Is there any way to amend it so that it could use my existing database instead of recreating another one.

Comment: I am not getting what you are telling dude how can you create a database with my code thats just a connection string right.First try to get credentials to LOGIN into MSSQL server and then create your DB and then try to access that DB using your application.

Comment: Well, thanks for the guidance. I've solved the problem by changing some part of my web config and it worked now. Thanks a lot for the enlightenment. :) And sorry for those stupid question as I am actually quite confused just now

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

1. Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections
   • Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
   • Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
   • Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
   • Enable local and remote connections
   • Restart instance
2. Check the SQL Server service account
   • If you are not using a domain account as a service account (for example if you are using NETWORK SERVICE), you may want to switch this first before proceeding
3. If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings in your ASweb P.NET application
   • Usually the format needed to specify the database server is machinename\instancename
   • Check your connection string as well

4.You may need to create an exception on the firewall for the SQL Server instance and port you are using
• Start > Run > Firewall.cpl
• Click on exceptions tab
• Add the sqlservr.exe (typically located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\MSSQL\Binn), and port (default is 1433)
• Check your connection string as well

1. If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings
2. Check SQLBrowser; check that it is running. You may also need to create an exception in your firewall for SQLBrowser.
3. Check that you have connectivity to the SQL Server. Note what you are using to connect: machine name, domain name or IP address? Use this when checking connectivity. For example if you are using myserver
   • Start > Run > cmd
   •netstat -ano| findstr 1433
   •telnet myserver 1433
   •ping -a myserver

Check what ports are IP addresses are being returned.

Alternative:
If you still can’t get any connection, you may want to create a SQL account on the server, a corresponding SQL user on the database in question, and just use this username/password combo in your web application.

Comment: But basically I have two projects with me. One was the previous one which used MSSQL and it works perfectly. The problem only lies with the current project.  So does that mean my MSSQL setup is having problem or just the database of project itself?

Comment: Check the differences in the connection strings. You are trying to connect to SQL Server Express with a connection string valid only for the full SQL Server product. I'll also bet that your previous project doesn't work on the same machine, or connects to a different server/database than the current project.

Comment: Dude define the connection string inside your web.config  itself and try.Like,

Comment: Yeah, it's connected to a different database which originally created in visual studio 2012. For the current project which with the problem, I used the database created from visual studio 2010 and modified the connection to use it in visual studio 2012. Does that caused the problem?

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible ways to get out of this type of error,

1. Change your connection string in this way, 
   Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SAFETY_AT_SG_DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True
2. Try by removing .mdf extension in connection string. Simply add database alone.
3. You have to give permission to access database, i.e., In sql server, Open Security => Login      => Right click => New login => Give proper name => then click on user mapping => Choose your database name => give permissions like execute, select (2005) or datareader, datawriter and son on..
4. Or else open sql service configuration. In this enable Tcp/Ip protocol, Start Sql server Broswer if it is in stop.
5. May be at sometime, firewall will block this sql server browser. So make it disable and try.

Change your connection string in this way,

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="GeospatialChallengeConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=local\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SAFETY_AT_SG_DATABASE;Integrated Security = True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Check the OP's connection strings. All these suggestions won't help if the connection string is wrong

Comment: For the third options, the tcp/ip protocol section shows me empty list like the image I posted above.

Comment: @9Dollars99Cents your image is not visible here. Can we know which version of MSSQL your using right now ?. Have you worked your previous project with same version ?